# dotnet HttpContext Claims doesn't match with JWT

Tags: .net-core, entity-framework-core, jwt, httpcontext

HttpContext Claims doesn't match with JWT.
I Tried Changed nameidentifier's value but context.user.claims value is always same.
The value changes only when I log in with a different account.

[image: My JWT PAYLOAD]

Get Claims Code:

```
public class HttpRequestInterceptor : DefaultHttpRequestInterceptor
{
    public override ValueTask OnCreateAsync(
        HttpContext context, 
        IRequestExecutor requestExecutor, 
        IQueryRequestBuilder requestBuilder, 
        CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        string? userId =
            context.User.FindFirstValue(ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier);
        string? role =
            context.User.FindFirstValue(ClaimTypes.Role);
        string? companyId =
            context.User.FindFirstValue(ClaimTypes.Actor);

        if(!string.IsNullOrEmpty(userId) && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(role) && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(companyId))
        {
            requestBuilder.SetProperty("currentUser",
                new CurrentUser(Guid.Parse(userId),Guid.Parse(companyId),role));
        }

        return base.OnCreateAsync(context, 
        requestExecutor, 
        requestBuilder, 
        cancellationToken);
    }
}
```

Result:
[image]

Program.cs :

```
var jwtSetting = jwtSettingSection.Get<JWTSettings>();
var signingKey = new SymmetricSecurityKey(
Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(jwtSetting.SecretKey!));
var tokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters
{
ValidateIssuer = true,
ValidateAudience = true,
ValidateIssuerSigningKey = true,
ValidIssuer = jwtSetting.ValidIssuer,
ValidAudience = jwtSetting.ValidAudience,
IssuerSigningKey = signingKey,
};
service
.AddAuthentication(JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
.AddJwtBearer(opt =>
{
    opt.TokenValidationParameters = tokenValidationParameters;
    opt.MapInboundClaims = false;
});
service.AddAuthorization();
```

Please Help me

Comment: Have you placed  [Authorize(AuthenticationSchemes = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)] on your controller?

Comment: i'm using hotchocolate(graphql) and get http conetxt user from HttpRequestInterceptor not controller